# Find the number of permutations of the 12 letters- A,C,D,G,H,I,K,N,O,R,S,T, which do not contain the pattern "GANDHI".

Tags: combinatorics

By my attempt, I am getting the answer to be $12!- 7×6!$.

But that does not seem to be correct.

Comment: How does it "not seem to be correct"? - does somebody claim that the solution is something else?

Comment: 'pattern' only means that the letters appear in the order - they don't have to be consecutive.

Comment: @JMP There are better/less ambiguous ways to say that, if that was the intent. Say, "... which doesn't contain letters G,A,N,D,H,I in that order..." The math problems should not turn into the discussion about interpreting _language_. I originally interpreted the problem the same as the OP. Also, if the problem was translated from another language, some meaning may have been lost.

Answer (score 1):

"Pattern" is different from "word", take the letters $G,A,N,D,H,I$ in that order to be *bars* in the stars and bars formula. Then the other $6$ letters can be placed and permuted  in

$$\binom {6+6}{6} 6!\;\, ways$$

Thus **do not contain** that pattern

$$= 12! - \binom{6+6}{6}\;\, ways$$

**Added**

If, by chance, you are wondering why there is no $-1$ in the upper and lower binomial indices, $6$ *bars* create $7$ *bins*, so you could write it as $\large\binom{6+7-1}{7-1}$ if you so like.

### P.S.

1. As Stinking Bishop has observed, the answer can be more simply obtained by placing  GANDHI in that order in $12$ slots and permuting the rest, so $12! - \binom{12}6 6!$
2. There is also the semantic point that the questioner might actually want $GANDHI$ with the letters together; in which case it would have been better to use the term **word** rather than **pattern**, and your attempt would be correct.

Comment: Why not just say "Out of $12$ positions, pick $6$ for the letters G,A,N,D,H,I: it can be done in $\binom{12}{6}$ ways"? No need to reference stars and bars.

Comment: @StinkingBishop: You are right, somehow stars and bars was the first thought that came to me. I'll add a PS.

Answer (score 1):

Place the letters from GANDHI anywhere into the $12$ slots, and then order them, and place the remaining letters anywhere. Or, just place the remaining letters anywhere, and add GANDHI.

$$\frac{P_6^{12}}{6!}6!=P_6^{12}=665,280$$

The final answer is then $12!-665,280=478,336,320$.